# Python program fails only if run (via ssh) from a mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, python, unicode, ascii

I am trying to run a python program on a data processing (linux) cluster. The program runs fine if I ssh to the cluster from my linux desktop and start it but fails if I ssh to the cluster from my mac laptop and try to run it I get the following error:

```
[muzzle@cluster]~% acme-calibrate detector DARK --in-folder /gpfs/acme/exp/instrument/201802/experiment1/raw --out-folder /home/muzzle/dark_out --run 28
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/boff/calframework/framework/extern/bin/acme-calibrate", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('acme-Offline-Calibration', 'console_scripts', 'acme-calibrate')()
  File "/home/boff/calframework/framework/extern/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 480, in load_entry_point
  File "/home/boff/calframework/framework/extern/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in load_entry_point
  File "/home/boff/calframework/framework/extern/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2322, in load
  File "/home/boff/calframework/framework/extern/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2328, in resolve
  File "/home/boff/pycalibrate_tmp/acme_calibrate/calibrate.py", line 236, in <module>
nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)
  File "/home/boff/calframework/framework/extern/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 141, in read
return reads(fp.read(), as_version, **kwargs)
  File "/home/boff/calframework/framework/extern/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 150: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It seems to be related to some conversion from UTF to ASCII, but I'm out of my depth.

I get the same error with both terminal.app and iterm2. Btw I used to have the iterm2 shell integration installed but I have removed them now.

The locale on the laptop is:

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

The locale on the remote server is:

```
% locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

This is the locale on my linux desktop, it is identical to that of the cluster:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Do both terminals use UTF-8? What are the `LANG` and `LC_*` variables in both cases? See `export | grep -E ' (LANG|LC_)'`

Comment: It looks to me like they do. I have added the output of locale to the question, if you want to take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the correct solution was to unset "Set locale environment variables on startup" in the terminal advanced options as described in https://blog.remibergsma.com/2012/07/10/setting-locales-correctly-on-mac-osx-terminal-application/

To do the same thing on iterm2 you have to unselect Preferences > Profiles > Terminal > Set locale variables automatically, as described here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83428/lang-variable-wrong-in-iterm2-wheres-the-bug

Answer (score 0):

The post
[OS X Terminal UTF-8 issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606570/os-x-terminal-utf-8-issues)
has some useful advice, based on
[A guide to help set up Terminal Apps](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060825071728278):

1. In *Terminal->Preferences->Settings->Advanced*:

   - Under **International**, ensure the character encoding is set to *Unicode (UTF-8)*.
   - Under **Emulation**, ensure that *Escape non-ASCII input with Control-V* is **not** set.

   This by itself may be enough to solve the problem.
2. Use the command `locale` and look at the `LC_CTYPE` line, which should
   end with `.UTF-8`.
   If it doesn't, then in bash `.profile` or `.bashrc` in the home directory,
   add a line like this:

   ```
   export LC_CTYPE=your-locale-here.UTF-8
   ```
3. Add the following lines to `.inputrc` in the home directory (create it if necessary):

   ```
   set meta-flag on
   set input-meta on
   set output-meta on
   set convert-meta off
   ```

You need to restart bash for the new settings to take effect.

Comment: I just tried all three steps but it did not work. Btw, I have added the output of locale to the question, if you want to take a look

Comment: It would be interesting to examine the differences in output of `locale` for linux and mac.

Comment: Hi @harrymc, I just added that to the description of the issue

Comment: Does the locale on the server differ if you connect from the Linux and from the Mac?

Comment: The locale on the desktop is identical to that of the cluster. I'll try to set my mac locale to the same

Comment: It looks like the correct solution was to unset "Set locale environment variables on startup" in the terminal advanced options

Comment: Yes, that overrode the `locale` settings on the server.